# How to count two different values from the same table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am somehow getting the multiple of two counts in MySQL 5.7 if I try to left join the same table.

My media table that looks like this:

```
create table merchants_product_media
(
    MERCHANT_ID  tinyint unsigned                           not null,
    SKU          char(10)                                   not null,
    TYPE         enum ('image', 'video')                    null,
    STATUS       enum ('active', 'unused') default 'active' null,
    primary key (MERCHANT_ID, SKU, URL),
)
```

There are also the tables merchants and manufacturers_products.

Now I want to know the amount of images and videos for a specific SKU from a merchant:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(med_p.TYPE) AS IMAGE,
   COUNT(med_v.TYPE) AS VIDEO
FROM
    merchants m CROSS JOIN manufacturers_products p
    LEFT JOIN merchants_product_media med_p ON med_p.SKU = p.SKU AND med_p.MERCHANT_ID = m.id AND med_p.TYPE = 'image' AND med_p.STATUS = 'active'
    LEFT JOIN merchants_product_media med_v ON med_v.SKU = p.SKU AND med_v.MERCHANT_ID = m.id AND med_v.TYPE = 'video' AND med_v.STATUS = 'active'
WHERE
      m.ID IN ( '2' )
    AND p.SKU = '44444'
GROUP BY m.id, p.SKU;
```

The correct result would be: 9 and 3
Instead I do get 27 and 27

If I change 'video' to 'testin'. The correct 9 for images is returned.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should aggregate each table in a separate subquery, and then join to them.  That aside, the cross join you have in there looks suspicious.  Why are you doing it?

Comment: `SUM(med_p.TYPE = 'image')` instead of COUNT().

Comment: Why do you cross join in this query ?

Comment: The result with SUM is the same as with COUNT. I am using the cross join because the merchant_id is within the merchant table, returning the merchant info. The manufacturers_products are listed in the other table. Every merchant offers some of the manufacturers products, but there is no relation between the two. Hence the cross join.

Comment: Actually @Akins sollution solved the issue, I just needed to remove the second LEFT JOIN.